# Гоголь-моголь

Tags: этимология

С детства все знают, что такое гоголь-моголь. Но вот что это за название? Или это просто игра слов и звуков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При кажущейся схожести названия с фамилией Гоголь писатель никакого отношения к сему десерту не имеет. Фасмер говорит о заимствовании слова из англ. hug-mug, hugger-mugger или объясняет близкое польск. kogel-mogel – то же из нем. Kuddelmuddel "**мешанина**". На Грамоте.ру дается немецкое соответствие Gogel-Mogel. Есть еще легенда  о канторе из Могилёва по фамилии Гогель, потерявшем голос. Чтобы вылечить горло, он придумал такой рецепт: «Взять сырую яичку, кокнуть в кружку, покрошить чернухи (то есть чёрного хлеба), посолить и взболтать». Он принимал лекарство понемногу, маленькой ложечкой. А поскольку Гогель из Могиля (Могилева) был человеком небогатым, то оно служило ему также и сытным завтраком. В другой версии этой же легенды присутствует графиня Бронислава Потоцкая, которая несколько модернизировала рецепт, заменив хлеб на мёд, и переименовала его из «гугель-моголь» в «гугол-моголь». (см. http://www.russianfood.com/reading/?post_id=227/) Мне больше нравится версия заимствования от Фасмера. Не наша это еда, и названия тоже не наши.

Comment: Olsa, "...писатель никакого отношения к сему десерту не имеет никакого отношения". Будьте внимательнее. 

Comment: Не стоит подобное писать в ответах.
Впрочем, по мне - так вообще не стоит. Особенно без слова "пожалуйста".